# Objects appear lit even if there is no light source

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, lighting

I'm working on a render and every time I render it as an image, using cycles, it's all lit up (which I don't want).

As you can see in the screenshot, the image is bright even without light sources!

[image: image is way too bright without light sources]

[the blend file](https://www.mediafire.com/file/4fo8kemntz9w50z/thumbnailblendtest2.blend/file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your shaders, you shouldn't plug a texture directly into the "*Material*" output.

If you don't want your shader to emit light, but only to diffuse external light based on its color, then add a *Diffuse* shader.

[image]

PS: you can tell that a shader is probably wrong when there is a line between two differently-colored sockets. In your case, yellow ("color info") sockets were connected to green ("shader info") sockets.